# How can I increase length of y-axis in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts. The JavaScript which I am using:

```
function drawChart3() {
    var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Day', 'Sales','exp'],
        ['4-APRIL-16', 1000,200],
        ['5-APRIL-16', 1170,300],
        ['6-APRIL-16', 660,400],
        ['7-APRIL-16', 1030,500],
        ['8-APRIL-16', 60,4100],
        ['9-APRIL-16', 130,5020],
        ['10-APRIL-16', 60,4100],
        ['11-APRIL-16', 130,5020],
    ]);

    var options3 = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    };

    var chart3 = new  google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart3.draw(data3, options3);
```

If you see the image of the page the y axis labels of date is not well aligned. How can I align them properly?

[image]

Comment: Note your code example is incomplete, missing a bracket. Make sure there’s no trivial error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options available. The dimensions of a chart will be set by:

- The dimensions of the containing element, or:
- By setting the height and width properties in the options for the chart.

The following will show you both approaches adapted from your code.

http://jsbin.com/televe/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Either:

```
#curve_chart {
  width: 200px;
}
```

or

```
var options4 = {
  title: 'Company Performance',
  curveType: 'function',
  height: 400,
  width: 300,
  legend: {
  position: 'bottom'
  }
};
```

The widths are up to you.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_customizing_chart#specify-options